# neo4j: user defined procedure exception "Write operations are not allowed for `READ` transactions"

Tags: neo4j

I have implemented a user defined procedure using the [example template](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template).

The procedure is annotated using "@Procedure(value = "foo.bar", mode = Mode.WRITE)", nevertheless, when I try to execute an operation on a Node instance that modifies the graph, it fails with "Write operations are not allowed for `READ` transactions".

The node instance was obtained via *db.findNode*(...), and the write-operation that I am attempting to execute is *nodeinstance.createRelationshipTo*(...)

Interestingly, the code works fine when run in the context of the neo4j testing harness.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you open transaction inside procedure?

Comment: Yes, the line of code is "try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {", same as the example procedure.

Interestingly, the code works fine when run in the context of my tests.

Comment: How are you calling the procedure? (from Neo4j Browser, using java driver, etc?)

Comment: calling the procedure from Neo4j Browser, when the procedure is called via one of my tests against the neo4j harness, works fine.

Comment: Is there another user defined procedure on github that I can inspect that implements a user defined procedure and that does write operations to the graph?  I looked at GraphAware's TimeTree, but it does not seem to implement the neo4j annotations for user defined procedures...uses an older point of integration to neo4j?

I will take a look at apoc, to see if I can learn anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From inspecting the APOC user defined procedures, I learned the answer.  I am using neo4j 3.0.7, for 3.0.x a procedure that wants to write to the graph must be annotated with "@PerformsWrites", as well as "@Procedure". The mode argument", mode = Mode.WRITE", is for 3.1, and "@PerformsWrites" is for 3.0.x -- learned this from Stefan Armbruster