# @PerformsWrites usage error: cannot use mode other than Mode.DEFAULT

Tags: neo4j, pom.xml

I am using the procedure-compiler in my pom file. Adding it and building gives the error in the title.
I learned here: [neo4j: user defined procedure exception "Write operations are not allowed for `READ` transactions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257822/neo4j-user-defined-procedure-exception-write-operations-are-not-allowed-for-r) that the @Procedure annotation is the old way before 3.1. However i am on 3.2.2.
Disabling the compiler and building seems to work fine so i am sure it is a false positive error. How do i silence it so i can use the compiler again?

Here is one example:

```
  @Procedure(value = "WL.CreateArgumentGroup", mode = Mode.WRITE)
    @Description("Takes node id's and create a new arg group with those nodes as premises")
    public Stream<LongResult> CreateArgumentGroup(@Name("nodeIds") List<Long> nodeIds)
```

Pom code:

```
  <properties>
    <neo4j.version>3.2.2</neo4j.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>procedure-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code-snippet in the question ?

Comment: Sure, appended to question